# How to download a huge console output from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

My job executes ansible-playbook in debug-mode (ansible-playbook -vvv) which generates a lot of output.

After the job finished, its very difficult to search using browser because its very slow and stuck.

I tried to download it with curl/wget, but the file is incomplete  (i guess only about 10% was downloaded)

```
curl http://j:8080/job/my-job/5/consoleText -O 

wget http://j:8080/job/my-job/5/consoleText
```

curl returns with error:

> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Comment: Try to download http://j:8080/job/my-job/5/consoleFull

Comment: @NoamHelmer i tried /consoleFull and curl failed for the same reason: "curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining"

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
curl -u "admin":"admin" "http://localhost:8080/job/my-job/5/logText/progressiveText?start=0"
```

If that doesn't work. I think your best option is to get the log from the server itself. The log can be found at `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log`.